# Deliver JMS message to all nodes in the cluster in Weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, weblogic, weblogic9.x

Is there a way to configure WebLogic 9.x cluster to receive a JMS message on a single JMS queue address from remote client and that the message is delivered to each cluster node? Any links would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a JMS queue has a point-to-point semantics - each message is delivered exactly once. If you want to deliver to all listeners, you need to use a Topic rather than a Queue.